# rails: undefined method `encoding' for #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:xxxxxxxx>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, file-upload, encoding, controller

Could someone please help me debug this error I get when trying to submit a file upload in rails?

```
NoMethodError in NationsController#create

undefined method `encoding' for #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x2d475c8>
```

Environment:

> Windows 7 (64bit)
>
> ruby -v  =
>
> ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22) [i386-mingw32]
>
> rails -v =
>
> DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
>
> Rails 4.1.1

Files:

nations/new.erb:

```
<%= form_for :nation, url: nations_path do |f| %>
  ...
  <p>
    <%= f.label :Upload_flag %>
    <%= f.file_field :flag %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit :Post %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

nations_controller.rb:

```
def create 

  @nation = Nation.new(nation_params)

  if @nation.save
     redirect_to @nation
  else
    render 'new'
  end

  private
  def nation_params
    params.require(:nation).permit(:name, :ruler, :government, :description, :flag)
  end

end
```

The code line that is highlighted as containing the error is:

```
@nation = Nation.new(nation_params)
```

Full trace and request:

```
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:47:in `binary_to_string'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/column.rb:105:in `type_cast'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:102:in `_field_changed?'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:78:in `save_changed_attribute'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:66:in `write_attribute'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:47:in `__temp__66c61676'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:45:in `public_send'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:45:in `_assign_attribute'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:32:in `block in assign_attributes'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:26:in `each'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:26:in `assign_attributes'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/core.rb:452:in `init_attributes'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/core.rb:198:in `initialize'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:30:in `new'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:30:in `new'
app/controllers/nations_controller.rb:21:in `create'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:676:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'

Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"78m9sOtlwoTKfAUdysKZoLiDHU4ikX/cVs8epIbEuag=",
 "nation"=>{"name"=>"sdfsf",
 "ruler"=>"sdfsdf",
 "government"=>"green",
 "description"=>"sdfsdfsdf",
 "flag"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x2dcc5a0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:C:/Users/JFR/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20140624-5808-bnuxjh>,
 @original_filename="cane2008.png",
 @content_type="image/png",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"nation[flag]\"; filename=\"cane2008.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">},
 "commit"=>"Post"}

Toggle session dump

_csrf_token: "78m9sOtlwoTKfAUdysKZoLiDHU4ikX/cVs8epIbEuag="
session_id: "e874179e9713d0a2009b5908423f7290"

Toggle env dump

GATEWAY_INTERFACE: "CGI/1.1"
HTTP_ACCEPT: "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: "gzip, deflate"
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: "it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3"
HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL: "max-age=0"
REMOTE_ADDR: "127.0.0.1"
REMOTE_HOST: "127.0.0.1"
SERVER_NAME: "localhost"
SERVER_PROTOCOL: "HTTP/1.1"

Response

Headers:

None
```

As explained at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files there is no need to set form's encoding to "multipart/form-data" when using form_for (as opposed to using form_tag).
What can it be then? I fear that I'm experiencing some incompatibilities issues between ruby and rails version? Any quick fix? Thanks.

Comment: Hi I am new to ROR.while trying the file upload I also having same error. Wat's wrong in it??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot assign a file object to a binary column and save it. If you *really* want to just save the file's contents to the database, call `read` on it before assigning it to your model. You probably want to do something more suited for file uploads, though. Take a look at [CarrierWave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) and [Paperclip](http://www.thoughtbot.com/projects/paperclip)

Comment: I was actually trying to avoid them to understand how it worked without. I found something at http://arjunurs.blogspot.it/2011/04/rails-saving-and-displaying-images-from.html but it looks a bit poor.. If you know more or have more resources please post them, thank you.